# Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2/py.typed' ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python in Anaconda Python 3.6

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, anaconda, conda

I am following the env setup in CenterPose repo. However, opencv-python doesn't get installed.

`(CenterPose) mona@ada:/data/CenterPose/data$ pip install opencv-python`

I get this error:

```
  -- Installing: /tmp/pip-install-wjrf6kvm/opencv-python_e5e6222fa4024d2d8f3e1d1c3bd5fb1f/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml
  -- Installing: /tmp/pip-install-wjrf6kvm/opencv-python_e5e6222fa4024d2d8f3e1d1c3bd5fb1f/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
  Copying files from CMake output
  creating directory _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/python-3/cv2.abi3.so -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/cv2.abi3.so
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/__init__.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/__init__.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/load_config_py2.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/load_config_py2.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/load_config_py3.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/load_config_py3.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/config.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/config.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/config-3.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/config-3.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/CenterPose/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/CenterPose/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/CenterPose/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 249, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o9p39xto/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 231, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o9p39xto/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o9p39xto/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o9p39xto/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 537, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 310, in main
      cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o9p39xto/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 683, in setup
      cmake_install_dir,
    File "setup.py", line 450, in _classify_installed_files_override
      raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
  Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2/py.typed'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

To reproduce:

```
CenterPose_ROOT=/path/to/clone/CenterPose
git clone https://github.com/NVlabs/CenterPose.git $CenterPose_ROOT
conda create -n CenterPose python=3.6
conda activate CenterPose
pip install -r requirements.txt
conda install -c conda-forge eigenpy
```

a bit sys info:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: why use python 3.6?

Comment: It is the requirement needed for CenterPose!

Comment: then it's a "CenterPose" problem. they should try 3.7 at least.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Merv's answer fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last OpenCV version to have wheels built for Python 3.6 was v4.6. With that in mind, I was able to get everything installed by explicitly restricting to that version.

Here is a standalone YAML that handles everything needed for environment creation (this doesn't require repository cloning):

**CenterPose_py36.yaml**

```yaml
name: CenterPose
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip
  - pip:
    - opencv-python==4.6.*
    - opencv-python-headless==4.6.*
    - -r https://github.com/NVlabs/CenterPose/raw/6c89d420b33bd01c14c13f509af08bfe3d8b2fe7/requirements.txt
```

I verified this works on [a `micromamba-docker` image](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), simply using:

```bash
micromamba create -n CenterPose -f CenterPose_py36.yaml
```

On `conda`, the command would be:

```bash
conda env create -n CenterPose -f CenterPose_py36.yaml
```